# How can I use jEdit editor to code in Objective C on Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, windows-7, jedit

I'm new to Objective C.
I've installed jEdit on windows 7 and the gcc compiler too.
I need to know how to use jEdit to develop Objective C applications on windows

Thank you.

Comment: Jedit is a just a text editor.  It happens to be _my_ favorite text editor, but it is not a full-blown IDE like MS Visual Studios or Eclipse.    To use a text editor to develop code, you just create a new file like hello_world.cpp and edit away.  Later, you compile the code on the command line ( start->run->cmd.exe or cygwin...) using g++ or whatever the objective c compiler is.

Answer (score 1):

You just write the code in jEdit(with .m extension for files) and compile it. If you want to develop iPhone apps, you would have to do some other stuff because it would require extra libraries that's native to Macs. Easiest way would be to get a Mac, or you can look here for some info on doing it in windows:

http://www.taranfx.com/how-to-develop-iphone-apps-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an Objective C compiler, plus a set of frameworks like GNUstep. You can get both at http://www.gnustep.org. Work is ongoing, but there's a lot left to do, especially on Windows.